# Add class "max-length" on textarea when it exceeds the maxlength="10" | Angular 4

Tags: angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular4-forms

I want to add class name "max-length" when user enters the characters more than 200 on textarea | Angular 2 format

`<textarea class="form-control" id="input" name="input" maxlength="200" placeholder="Placeholder" cols="10" rows="5">Value</textarea>`

Answer (score 0):

You can add a change event on input and get the length check following and based on a validation can have a class added:

HTML:

```
<textarea class="form-control {{dynamicClass}}" (change)="valueChange($event)" id="input" name="input" maxlength="200" placeholder="Placeholder" cols="10" rows="5">Value</textarea>
```

TS:
define this variable in your class:

```
dynamicClass: string;
```

following is your method:

```
valueChange(event){
   if(event.target.value.length > 200){
     this.dynamicClass = "max-length";
   }
}
```